# Constructors to type T

Tags: c++, templates, types, constructor

I am working on Goodrich/Tamassia "Data Structures" book, and I cannot really understand what they mean in one of the questions:
The question asks to implement a templated C++ class "Vector" (with type T) that would behave like STL "vector" with the following extensions: It should support addition, subtraction, and multiplication. This part is easy and I know how to make an operator. The question also says **"Type T should have constructors T(0) - producing the additive identity element, and T(1) - producing multiplicative identity element."** This is the part I don't understand. How do I create a constructor for templated type T? And what should it do? Thank you

[Problem 2.3 of Data Structures and Algorithms in C++ by Goodrich/Tamassia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqUN7.png)

Comment: Think, which types have constructors `T(0)` and `T(1)` ;)? Hint: `int`...

Comment: The Vector class cannot provide a constructor for the type T. I think the authors are describing an **implicit template parameter requirement** that the user of the Vector class template will have to obey. That said, it is not clear from your description why these requirements are necessary.

Comment: I don't have the book. But given the context, I'm guessing that it means that your template may assume and require that `T` has such constructors. It's the responsibility of the user of the template to provide the constructors, not your's (as the designer of the template).

Comment: The condition seems to be sloppily stated. It should be something like this: "Assume that the statement `T t0(0), t1(1);` is well-formed for some invented variables `t0`, `t1`."

Comment: @KerrekSB Standardese to the rescue :) (You'd also need to add the identity requirements - perhaps "for any variable `t` of type `T`, the expressions `t + t0 == t` and `t * t1 == t` evaluate to `true`".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create constructors for existing types (without modifying code if the type is a class). The question does not specify this, it states (badly) that `T` should *have* at least one constructor to take values 0 and 1.

Basically, what this means is that `T` should be able to yield values 0 and 1, as (almost) every fundamental types are able to. An `int`, for instance, can have 0 or 1 as values.

**Edit** :
Now that you have added the whole question, I can read what I expected : it states that `T` supports addition, subtraction and multiplication. The "identity elements" part is not very important, it just adds some kind of correctness. As stated, your class shall be templated with any numerical scalar type. This is what most fundamental types are.

**Original** :
*However, a more thorough question would state that `T` should support addition, subtraction and multiplication, since the `Vector` class itself is meant to support these (and there is no real need for special values like 0 or 1). The fact is, you will most likely use that kind of vector with fundamental types like `int` or `double`, so you do not need to worry about it.*

So, the question essentially states that your `T` type should have what you need to implement addition, subtraction and multiplication for your `Vector`. You have nothing to do about it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is actually helpful!

Answer (score 2):

For a type T, the element producing the additive identity is T i such as whatever T j you take,  it is guaranteed that j + i = j.

In other words, it is the equivalent of 0 for the type T.  It will be 0 in case of int, 0.0 in case of doubles, "" in case of strings, {0.0,0.0} in case of complex, etc...

For the multiplicative identity i, the principle is the same. It is T i such as whatever T j you take, j * i = j.  You can guess that for int it will be 1, for double 1.0,  etc...

I think the question says that the type T should have such an element (assumption).  So you can use it.  But It doesn't say that you have to define it.

Comment: What if someone uses a <string> as a type?

Comment: The standard strings have operator+ and additive identity.  However they don't have multiplication, so they won't be suitable for this vector class.  They are mentionned here only as example for the concept additive identiy, and to highlight that T can be something else than just plain numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, the disputable quote dictates that the allowable types for `T` in the usable context of your `class vector<T>` should support the identities for addition and multiplication.

Nevertheless, with the help of type traits and in particular `std::enable_if` you could create a `class vector<T>` that would only compile if `T` supports the identities for addition and multiplication, like the example below:

```
namespace detail {
  template<typename T, class Enable = void> class vector;

  template<typename T>
  class vector<T, typename std::enable_if<T(0) + T(1) == T(1) && T(1) * T(1) == T(1)>::type> {
    // ...
  };

  template<typename T, template<typename> class C>
  class vector<C<T>, typename std::enable_if<T(0) + T(1) == T(1) && T(1) * T(1) == T(1)>::type> {
    // ...
  };
}
```

### [**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98c0bb718cd9da66)

Comment: Thanks for the example and the demo!

Comment: You can create a type `T` where `T(1)*T(1) == T(1)` but `T(2)*T(1) != T(2)`. The same goes for addition. So why would you bother with `enable_if` ? Just trust the user, there is nothing else (not ugly) you can do about it (when I say "trust the user", it is more like "let the user do whatever he wants but provide him a good tool").